# GLSL error C3012: invalid value 8 for layout specifier 'binding' in compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am using a GeForce GTX 670, am I really limited to only 8 layout specifiers?

I really thought it would be more than that... my GL_MAX_IMAGE_UNITS is 30k+

Heres some example code from my compute shader that gives the error:

```
layout (local_size_x = 256) in;

layout (rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform image1D a;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 1) uniform image1D b;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 2) uniform image1D c;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 3) uniform image1D d;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 4) uniform image1D e;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 5) uniform image1D f;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 6) uniform image1D g;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 7) uniform image1D h;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 8) uniform image1D i;

void main(void)
{ 
}
```

If I use "location" instead of "binding", the shader will compile, but will not write to any of the textures...

Comment: Where are you getting 30k+ from? The specification for GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store only requires a minimum of 8, and on all of my test hardware this is all the drivers will give me :)

Comment: Doh, I assumed the value in GL_MAX_IMAGE_UNITS would correspond. My mistake! 8 still seems rather low though :(

Comment: Yeah, what you want to query is GL_MAX_COMPUTE_IMAGE_UNIFORMS. Unfortunately, its minimum requirement is also 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8 image units is the minimum that the GL 4.3 specification requires. And it's likely to be the standard for current hardware.

However, there's no reason why you should be limited by that. Just use a [1D array texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture); that way, you can write to as many "1D textures" as you want.